# RSA public key prime numbers. Finding prime numbers p and q given n=p*q and e

Tags: security, math, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I have a public key n and the RSA exponent e = 0x10001. I wanted to see if someone can guide me on how I can find p and q? I don't have access to the private key.

n = 0xAA0CA29282E466FC5E5A5DD973413EF3B464EF83B112168A4577A8BB1FF0703D6EED80574D2EECD2F9F447BC32B9B91BA8B4239E24BDA681B6C3AAA2566BA41AB8CB9F93D2B7D4D8FD2E3F2584964F7F50E48794F057451D0F67355A4488C478BF7FDD680A95B51B0006D4823D59CE4BEF9872E2AE18EFDDE560475524D0B6965D6465D0F54E07B2A3EE2CBCB18C3E6FED2836301C0E3FEFE0579921EA77FC09A48596BB9EBB32B809B550716A38C9EE68D079F8A9F0AB5DF90B63F537D319778FC372703AC94D21C1C719B34A9D479D0BE735BED86EF9ACEF6A278E37877DB2A0D65CB4D793ABD3889D591A33974B39EB3CAD6262EE8AA6ADB43275A483D145

Comment: Pffft, easy. Just sign up for Amazon's Web Services quantum computing platform. I think the price is a bit steep today, but it might be cheaper in a few years. Voting to close as not programming related.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to see if someone can guide me on how I can find *p* and *q*?

The security of RSA relies on this being impossible, because *p* and *q* can be used to calculate the private key.

Your public key is 2048 bits long, which is well into the range that's considered secure (i.e, practically impossible to factor) today. So, in short, you can't.

(It's possible that there is something unusual about the structure of this *n* which makes it easy to factor. But I'll assume this isn't the case.)